# method in Cassandra Repository with query annotation, returning a different return type from that specified in method definition

Tags: java, cassandra, cql, spring-data-cassandra

I am testing Cassandra as a database using cassandra-spring-data. I have defined a simple table like below

```
@Data
@Table
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class User {
  @PrimaryKey
  private String id;
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
  private String country;

  public User(String id) {
     this.id = id;
  }

  public User(String id, String country) {
     this.id = id;
     this.country = country;
  }

}
```

I have inserted different users into the database I am trying to group by country and count for each country the number of users. I created this class for the return type of this query.

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CountryAndNumUsers {
  private String country;
  private int numberOfUsers;
}
```

this is the repository interface below

```
public interface UserRepository extends CassandraRepository<User, String> {


  @Query("Select country, count(*) as numberOfUsers from user group by id, country")
  List<CountryAndNumUsers> getListOfCountryAndNumUsers();
}
```

when call the method getListOfCountryAndNumUsers() from application class it crashes with the error

```
    ...Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Required property numberOfUsers not 
found for class com.example.springbootcasandrademo.model.User!
```

From the error it tries to return a User object instead of a CountryAndNumUsers object